# Problem updating prices and stock of products in woocommerce from a database in MySQL in the query using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, woocommerce

The main problem is to formulate the correct query, '$ select_sentence' which I am using takes the last value of the new price 'New Price' in the base db and places it in all woocommerce products. I should compare 'id' = _sku but I haven't succeeded, any suggestions?

```
$select_sentence = "SELECT id, newPrice FROM products";

$result = mysqli_query($dbNewPrice , $select_sentence);
 if (!$result) {
  printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_error($dbNewPrice));
exit();
  }

$update_sentence = "UPDATE wp_postmeta 
                    SET meta_value=? 
                    WHERE meta_key like '_sku'=? 
                    AND meta_key like '_price'";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbWooCommerce, $update_sentence)) {

foreach ($result as $newData) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
        $stmt, "sd",
          $newData['newPrice'], 
          $newData['id']
    );
    if (!$update_result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($sentencia));
        exit();
      }
    }
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($dbWooCommerce);
mysqli_close($dbNewPrice );
```

Comment: here you are makeing two dffrent comparosions meta_key like '_sku'=?  that makes no sense what dou you try to compare to id?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query